# Определение в дистантном положении всегда отделять запятой?

Tags: определения, пунктуация

Египетское правительство планирует заложить к востоку от Каира новую столицу государства с семимиллионным населением, где будут находиться правительственные учреждения.

Нужно ли перед *с* поставить запятую, чтобы обособить несогласованное определение *с семимиллионным населением*, относящееся к слову *столицу*?

Comment: без запятой можно подумать, что это государство с семимиллионным населением.А в Каире, нынешней столице, - около 20 миллионов.

Comment: @doom, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 3):

Нет, не всегда, здесь запятая, на мой взгляд, не нужна, несогласов. определение не подчёркивает выражаемое им значение, но если для вас важна цифра СЕМИМИЛЛИОННОЕ население, можно выделить (если раньше была маленькая столица, а теперь большая).

Comment: 

Имеем сочетания: "столицу (какую?) с семимиллионным населением", "государства (какого?) с семимиллионным населением". 


???

Comment: Ну да, верно, только я что-то в эту сторону не подумала (что кто-то может отнести определение к государству).